# Find ALL keys of highest value in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I know that this question looks like its been asked but this variation has not. I have a dictionary with the values {'John': 10, 'Chase': 11, 'Cole': '11'}. If i use the max function, I'll only get the first value with the max (Chase). However in my program, I need to get all of the values (Chase and Cole). Any help? I have 2 separate lists that are also combined into a dictionary. I have done:

```
for value in array1dictionary:
    if value == max(array1list):
        maxkeyarray.append(key)
```

but that does not work. Any advice?

Comment: first find the max value then use a for loop to check the all the values if it equals to max value add it to the list

Comment: What do u wanna get? The key or the value or both?

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762332/how-to-get-all-the-keys-with-the-same-highest-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
dictt = {'John': 10, 'Chase': 11, 'Cole': '11'}

max_val = max(dictt.values(), key = lambda x: int(x))

maxkeyarray = [key for key in dictt if int(dictt[key]) == max_val]

print(maxkeyarray)
```

Output:

```
['Chase', 'Cole']
```

Comment: @DIDieure Seyee Did my code work for u?