# Print the students with the top marks

Tags: python

Q: Print all the students with the top marks. If multiple students have the same mark, print both students.

Sample Output:

```
Best student(s): Micheal Murphy, Dan Smith
Best mark: 89
```

My code:

```
import sys

def procfile(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            bestMark = -1
            for line in f:
                mark, name = line.strip().split(maxsplit=1)
                mark = int(mark)
                if mark > bestMark:
                   bestMark, bestStudent = mark, name
            print(f'Best student(s): {bestStudent}')
            print(f'Best mark: {bestMark}')

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f'The file {filename} cannot be opened')

procfile(sys.argv[1])
```

My output that I am getting:

```
Best student(s): Michael Murphy
Best mark: 89
```

My problem:

How do I make it so that it prints multiple students that achieved the top mark?
I want my output to be

```
Best student(s): Micheal Murphy, Dan Smith
Best mark: 89
```

Comment: At least you include a [example] in the question...

Comment: Related / alternative approaches (requires reading the whole thing into memory first): [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823227/how-to-get-all-the-maximums-max-function) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762332/how-to-get-all-the-keys-with-the-same-highest-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list to store the student names:

```
def procfile(filename): 
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            bestMark = -1
            for line in f:
                mark, name = line.strip().split(maxsplit=1)
                mark = int(mark)
                # better mark: create new list
                if mark > bestMark:
                   bestMark, bestStudents = mark, [name]

                # same mark again: add to the list
                elif mark == bestMark:
                   bestStudents.append(name)
                   
            print(f'Best student(s): {", ".join(bestStudents)}')
            print(f'Best mark: {bestMark}')

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f'The file {filename} cannot be opened')

with open("t.txt", "w") as f:
  f.write("20 John\n30 Bill\n20 Lisa\n30 Nobody")
procfile("t.txt")
```

Output:

```
Best student(s): Bill, Nobody
Best mark: 30
```

---

You can also do all students:

```
def procfile(filename):
    students = {}
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            bestMark = -1
            for line in f:
                mark, name = line.strip().split(maxsplit=1)
                mark = int(mark)
                students.setdefault(mark,[]).append(name)
                  
            print(f'All student(s):')
            for key in sorted(students, reverse=True):
                print(key, "by", ', '.join(students[key]))
          
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f'The file {filename} cannot be opened')

with open("t.txt", "w") as f:
  f.write("20 John\n30 Bill\n20 Lisa\n30 Nobody")
procfile("t.txt")
```

Output:

```
All student(s):
30 by Bill, Nobody
20 by John, Lisa
```

Computationally its not much worse, you just need some more memory to store the dictionary. You can speed the progam up if you do thousands of students by using a `collections.defaultdict` instead of a normal dict using `dict.setdefault`.